# Angularjs : $http load a page ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs

in sample.html  -- >  ng-repeat not working . It seems angularjs couldn't compiler this new page .

How to add this new page into angular system ? 
or can i make it in other way ? 
please help me .

```js
myApp.controller('test' , function( $http , $scope ){
  
    $scope.load = function( url ){
         $http.get( url ).then( function( response ){
                
              $scope.modalbody = response.data ;
        } ) ;
    }
    
  
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller="test"> {{ modalbody | trustedhtml  }} 

      <button ng-click="load( 'sample.html'  )"></button>
  
 </div>
  
 in sample.html  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓   ng-repeat not working
 
 <div ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4]">{{x}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you send us your console error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let AngularJS load the template from the URL. The directive `ng-include` handles this for you. Interpolation doesn't compile HTML as you noticed.

```js
myApp.controller('test' , function( $http , $scope ){
    $scope.load = function( url ){
        $scope.loadedUrl = url;
    }
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller="test">

      <div ng-include="loadedUrl"></div>

      <button ng-click="load( 'sample.html'  )"></button>
  
 </div>
  
 in sample.html  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓   ng-repeat not working
 
 <div ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4]">{{x}}</div>
```

Comment: ng-include , yes , that's exactly what i want ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-init` :

```
<div ng-init="arr = [0,1,2,3,4]" ng-repeat="x in arr ">{{x}}</div>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` runs before `ng-init`, so arr wouldn't be defined on scope, see https://gist.github.com/awerlang/fea0da3b61cf1f4b1a8a